# Asymptotics of functions involving square roots

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I want to show that a function of the form $f(x)=\sqrt{x+a}+b$ with $a$ and $b$ some constants is, as $x\to\infty$, equal to
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{x}+O(x^r)
$$
for some $0<r<1/2$ (any such $r$ would be fine). Intuitively it seems to me that this should be true. Isn't it so? Or how can it be proved?

Comment: Write down $f(x) - \sqrt{x} = (\sqrt{x+a} - \sqrt{x}) + b$. What could you do with that?

Comment: What about $b$.

Comment: Alright! $\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt x$ goes to zero, so that the remainder term is bounded by a constant. I completely missed that... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has basically been answered in the comment by Daniel Fischer. I reproduce it here:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt x)(\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x)}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x)}
$$

$$
=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac a {\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x}=0.
$$

Therefore,
$$
f(x)=\sqrt x+O(1).
$$
(And we could even take $r=0$).

Comment: In the question we have $r>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Just a **Hint**

Near $+\infty$,

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x}(1+\frac{a}{x})^\frac 12+b$$

$$=\sqrt{x}(1+\frac{a}{2x}(1+\epsilon(x))+b$$

$$=\sqrt{x}+\frac{a}{2\sqrt{x}}(1+\epsilon(x))+b$$

$$=\sqrt{x}+x^{\frac{1}{4}}(\frac{a}{2x^{\frac{3}{4}}}+\frac{b}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}})$$

$$=\sqrt{x}+x^{\frac{1}{4}}\epsilon(x)$$

$$=\sqrt{x}+O(x^{\frac{1}{4}}).$$

Comment: Where did 1/4 come from?

Comment: I have the same question. In the right hand side, as far as I can see, we only have $o(\sqrt x)$, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Federico What do you think now about the answer.

Comment: as $x \to \infty$ : $\sqrt{x+a}  = \sqrt{x} + \mathcal{O}(x^{-1/2})$. I know it because $\sqrt{x+a}  - \sqrt{x}= \int_x^{x+a}\frac12 t^{-1/2} dt = \mathcal{O}(x^{-1/2})$